# Rewrite folder to another sub-folder inside that folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to convert a request from a folder, to another sub-folder inside that folder. Let me explain:

Convert: **localhost/myproject/build/css/style.css**

To: **localhost/myproject/build/dev/css/style.css**

So, I need to add '/dev' to the request after 'build/' folder. What I have?:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^build/(.*) build/dev/$1
```

And I'm getting an infinite loop from Apache:

> [Thu Apr 24 17:56:39.721756 2014] [core:error] [pid 6980:tid 1660]
>   [client ::1:55569] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal
>   redirects due to probable configuration error. Use
>   'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use
>   'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

And I know what is happening, Apache is doing this:

```
build/css/style.css (original request)
build/dev/css/style.css 
build/dev/dev/style.css
build/dev/dev/dev/style.css
.... to the infinite
```

So I only need to catch an rewrite the request once. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a condition to skip adding `/dev` once it has been added:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^build/((?!dev/).*)$ build/dev/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/build/dev/(.*)
RewriteRule ^build/(.*) /build/dev/$1 [R=301]
```

The above will check and see if `build/dev/` is in the url already, it is the it won't redirect. You were getting it to add `dev/` if `build/` was in the url, which caused the redirect loop.

Comment: I get a loop with your suggestion :(

Comment: Try that, made a change.

Comment: Now I'm getting a 301 and next a 404. It's going from /mycompany/myproject/dmj/build/css/styles.css to /build/dev/css/styles.css